# How to write the SQL statement (Window function) in Teradata to get a derived column?

Tags: sql, teradata, window-functions

The source data is in a table (Teradata), please reference the attachment;the non-yellow part is original columns while yellow part are derived columns.
I want to use SQL statement of Teradata to get a derived column (the column of "final_result"):
Now the data of this table is order by operator, activity_finish_date

1. The column of 'induce_duration1' comes from: the current row of "activity_finish_date" minus the previous row of "activity_finish_date"
2. The column of 'induce_duration2' comes from: the current row of "activity_finish_date" minus the current row of "activity_start_date"
3. The column of "final_result" comes from: `min(induce_duration1, induce_duration2)`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your Teradata release supports LEAST/GREATEST on Timestamps:

```
activity_finish_date -                -- current finish
GREATEST(activity_start_date          -- current start
        ,LAG(activity_finish_date)    -- previous end
         OVER (PARTITION BY operator
               ORDER BY activity_finish_date)) HOUR(4) TO SECOND
```